# How to implement animation in angular2 with dart

Tags: angular, dart

Can someone help me understand how can I use angular2 animations in dart.

Documentation points to a `AnimationBuilder` class, but I was unable to even find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Dart Angular2 doesn't provide any animation support. `AnimationBuilder` was removed a while ago. 
You can use CSS animation and WebAnimations independent of Angular2 support with direct DOM access (using `dart:html`)